# Generalization of counting measure is a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X, \mathcal{P}(X) = M$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. Let $f: X \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a function. Define $\mu : M \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ by $\mu(E) = \sum_{x \in E} f(x)$, which Folland defines as $$\sup_{\substack{F \subset E \\ F \text{ finite}}} \sum_{x \in F} f(x).$$ Prove that $\mu$ is a measure.

It's easy to show that $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$ -- the empty sum is defined to be 0, but I'm having trouble showing $\sigma$-additivity. Here's what I've got so far:

Let $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^\infty \subset M$ be a collection of mutually disjoint sets, and let $E = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i$. For a fixed finite $F \subset E$, we have that $F = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^\infty F \cap E_i = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^k F\cap E_i$ and so: $$\sum_{x \in F} f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^k \left(\sum_{x \in F_i} f(x) \right)...$$ but it seems like this isn't a nicer expression I can work with.

Does anyone have any ideas? This is a homework question, so a strong hint will be appreciated over a full answer.

Comment: I would proceed by cases: if $\mu(E_i)=\infty$ for some i, than it should not be hard to show $\mu(\bigcup E_i)=\infty$. If the measure of the sets is all finite, just keep in mind that for each of them the x such that f(x)>0 is at most countable. Then using properties of series it shouldn't be difficult to conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this strong enough of a hint?

$\sum_{x \in F_i} f(x) = 0$ except for a finite number of indices, so $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \left(\sum\limits_{x \in F_i} f(x) \right) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \left(\sum\limits_{x \in F_i} f(x) \right)$$

Comment: I suppose. Taking supremums over the inner sum, we get $\mu(E_i)$, I believe?

Comment: Best not to be too cavalier with that. Certainly the inner sums are $\le \mu(E_i)$ since they are sums over finite subsets of the $E_i$. Proving the opposite inequality takes more finesse.

Comment: Alright, I guess I don't see the other direction then. How would I finesse that out?

Comment: $E_i \nearrow E$

Comment: I'm not getting much from that, sorry. I don't understand the notation.

Comment: Prove the equality for when $E$ is the union of a finite number of sets (since everything is finite, there is no problem). Then show that as you let $k \to \infty, \mu \left (\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k E_i \right ) \to \mu(E)$.