# Proving that the generalised counting measure is indeed a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\mathcal A$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on an arbitrary set $X$. I am
>   trying to prove that the function $\mu\colon \mathcal A\to[0,\infty]$
>   defined by $$\mu(A)=\sum_{x\in A}\alpha_x=\sup_{F\subset A\text{
>  finite}}\sum_{x\in F}\alpha_x$$ for any $A\in\mathcal A$ and some
>   function $\alpha\colon X\to[0,\infty]$, is $\sigma$-additive.

Taking mutually disjoint $A_i\in \mathcal A$ and letting $A=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$, we want to prove that $$\mu(A)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(A_i).$$ In order to see the general argument, I tried first to prove this for $A_1$ and $A_2$ (and $A_i=\emptyset$ for $i>2$). So, we want $$\sum_{x\in A_1\cup A_2}\alpha_x=\sum_{x\in A_1}\alpha_x+\sum_{x\in A_2}\alpha_x.$$That is, $$\sup_{F\subset A_1\cup A_2\text{ finite}}\sum _{x\in F}\alpha_x = \sup_{F\subset A_1\text{ finite}}\sum_{x\in F}\alpha_x +  \sup_{F\subset A_2\text{ finite}}\sum_{x\in F}\alpha_x.$$ Intuitively, I feel that this does not hold because as $A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint, $F$ on the left-hand side will be either a subset of $A_1$ or $A_2$, but not both at the same time. So, the left-hand side must be less than or equal to the right-hand side. But it has hold because $\mu$ is to be shown to be a measure.

Any help as to how I can prove this will be appreciated. I know this has been asked [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427239/generalization-of-counting-measure-is-a-measure), but that user asked for a hint and I can't say that I understand the answer he got. Just to clarify, this is not homework. It is given as an example of a "generalised counting measure" in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure) wikipedia article.

Comment: Think about $F\cap A_1$ and $F \cap A_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F_1\subset A_1$ and $F_2\subset A_2$ then, setting $F=F_1\cup F_2$,
$$\sum_{x\in F_1}a_x+\sum_{x\in F_2}a_x=\sum_{x\in F}a_x\le\sum_{x\in A_1\cup A_2}a_x.$$Taking the sup over $F_1$ and $F_2$ now gives $$\sum_{x\in A_1}a_x+\sum_{x\in A_2}a_x\le\sum_{x\in A_1\cup A_2}a_x.$$

Conversely, suppose $F\subset A_1\cup A_2$ and let $F_j=F\cap A_j$. Then
$$\sum_{x\in F}a_x=\sum_{x\in F_1}a_x+\sum_{x\in F_2}a_x\le\sum_{x\in A_1}a_x+\sum_{x\in A_2}a_x;$$taking the sup over $F$ shows $$\sum_{x\in A_1\cup A_2}a_x\le\sum_{x\in A_1}a_x+\sum_{x\in A_2}a_x.$$